# Can individual values of an enum implement an interface

Tags: java, enums

An `enum` can implement an interface.  Is it possible for some of the values to implement an interface?  The use case that I am thinking of is a tagging interface, so something like the following:

```
interface Foo {}
interface Bar {}

enum Widgets {
  FOO implements Foo,
  BAR_1 implements Bar,
  BAR_2 implements Bar
}
```

That does not compile under Java 1.8.  I know that internally, there are separate classes created for FOO and BAR_1, so it seems this is possible, but I can easily see the standard not supporting it.

Something similar that should work is

```
interface Widgets;
enum Foo implements Widgets { FOO };
enum Bar implements Widgets { BAR_1, BAR_2 };
```

This has the drawback that I cannot just do `Widgets.values()` and get all of the Widgets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1) states

> **The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an
>   anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately
>   enclosing enum type. The class body is governed by the usual rules of
>   anonymous classes**; in particular it cannot contain any constructors.
>   Instance methods declared in these class bodies may be invoked outside
>   the enclosing enum type only if they override accessible methods in
>   the enclosing enum type (§8.4.8).

An anonymous class can only extend (or implement) the type specified in the new instance creation expression, your `enum` type in this case. As such, you can't have it additionally implement an interface.

---

The following

```
enum Foo {
    CONSTANT
}
```

gets compiled to something similar to

```
class Foo extends Enum<Foo> {
    private Foo() {/* calling Enum superconstructor */}
    public static final Foo CONSTANT = new Foo();
}
```

If you wanted the constant to have a body (to override or declare some methods)

```
enum Foo {
    CONSTANT {
        public String toString() {
            return name().toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
```

becomes something like

```
class Foo extends Enum<Foo> {
    private Foo() {/* calling Enum superconstructor */}
    public static final Foo CONSTANT = new Foo() { // no way to express an additional interface
        public String toString() {
            return name().toUpperCase();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The enum values are not classes but instances, so they cannot implement an interface.

However, if what you want is just a way to "tag" your values, you can use a field:

```
enum Widgets {

  FOO(true, false),
  BAR_1(false, true),
  BAR_2(false, true),
  BOTH(true, true);

  private final boolean isFoo;
  private final boolean isBar;

  Widgets(boolean isFoo, boolean isBar) {
    this.isFoo = isFoo;
    this.isBar = isBar;
  }

  public boolean foo() {
    return isFoo;
  }

  public boolean bar() {
    return isBar;
  }
}
```

In that example, you will be able to enumerate your values with `Widgets.values()` and to know if each value is tagged "foo", "bar" or both.

An other method to "tag" you values can be:

```
enum Tag {
  FOO,
  BAR;
}

enum Widgets {

  FOO(Tag.FOO),
  BAR_1(Tag.BAR),
  BAR_2(Tag.BAR),
  BOTH(Tag.FOO, Tag.BAR);

  private Tag[] tags;

  Widgets(Tag... tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
  }

  public Tag[] getTags() {
    return tags;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that sometimes the values are a new class.  For example,

enum Foo {
  ONE { public String toString() { return "1" } },
  TWO { public String toString() { return "3" } };
}


I think most (all?) implementations will create two subclasses of Foo and create an instance of each (and no instances that are Foo).