# enum implementing interface with generic methods

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I have an interface:

```
public interface I {
    <T> T getValue();
    <T> void setValue(T diagram);
}
```

but when I set

```
enum E implements I {
        A {
            private C c;

            @Override
            public C getValue() {
                return c;
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(C c) {
                this.c = c;
            }
        };
    }
```

I have an error on the setValue method ("Method does not override method from its superclass"), why is it ok for the first method only to replace the generic ?

Thanks

Comment: The interface isn't generic. You have defined two totally independent generic methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type parameter `T` should be declared at the `interface` level, not separately for each method.

```java
public interface I<T> {
    T getValue();
    void setValue(T diagram);
}
enum E implements I<C> {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But what if I have A and B as enum elements and I want the generic for A to be different than the one for B such as public String getValue() for A and public Integer getValue() for B, is there a way ?

Comment: @FloFlo I don't think there's a good way to do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074768/can-individual-values-of-an-enum-implement-an-interface